# Group multiple strings into a generic one in Java

Tags: java, string, grouping

I've got to group multiple strings into one to make a comparison. This grouping should be done exactly like the Java OO paradigm: a string that "describes" the substring.
Example:

```
String one = "hammer";
String two = "screwdriver";
String three = "pliers";
```

Now let's say you want to "describe" them:

```
String str = "tool"
```

All strings above are tools. Now, my code have string one, two, three and change them into "tool". So, for example, string one become tool, the same for string two and string three.
How to "categorize" them?
Another extended example:

```
String one = "hammer"
String two = "screwdriver";
String three = "pliers";
String four = "horse";
String five = "cat";
String six = "dog";

public void stringConverter(String str)
{
    if ("string match to an animal")
        str = "animal";
    if ("string match to a tool")
        str = "tool";
}
```

Maybe it's a stupid thing to implement but right now I don't have any ideas! Thank you!

edit: my group is limited, I know that i have only cat, dog, horse, hammer, etc...
edit2: It's difficult to express me! It should be something like:

```
Group Animal = {cat, dog, horse}
Group Tools = {hammer, screwdriver}

// methods to recognize to wich one of the two groups is categorizable
```

The Map is a good idea but it has to be filled at every runtime. Isn't there something static like writing them directly into braces? It should be something like enums but never used before!

Comment: I don't know why you would ever want to do something like this, but just add all of the reference Strings into a Set for each category and then search the Sets for the test String. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: Compile time or runtime? (edit: the set of values and associated descriptions -- dynamic or static?)

Comment: The set of values is static, not runtime. @smp7d Maps are useful, but I've got to fill them and should be done one per time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a `Map` mapping strings to their "category."

```
Map<String, String> category = new HashMap<String, String>();
category.put("hammer", "tool");
category.put("screwdriver", "tool");
category.put("horse", "animal");
```

and then you just use `category.get(str)` to get the category.

If they're static, you're probably best served by a Guava [ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html), possibly using its builder syntax.

Comment: It is perfect! Is there a way to fill it in one way, without calling put() everytime?

Comment: Depends what you mean.  Where are you getting the categorizations?  There are a couple hacky ways to do it, but your best bet is either a) stick with the one-at-a-time `put` operations, or possibly use [Guava's ImmutableMap.builder()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html), if you can use third-party libraries.

Answer (score 6):

I'd start something like this.

```
public class Category
{
    private final String name;
    private final Set<String> items;

    public Category(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.items = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void add(String... items)
    {
        for (String item : items)
        {
            this.items.add(item);
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(String item)
    {
        return this.items.contains(item);
    }
}
```

Then,

```
Category tools = new Category("tool");
tools.add("hammer", "screwdriver", "pliers");

Category animals = new Category("animal");
animals.add("horse", "dog", "cat");
```

And finally,

```
// Guava for brevity
List<Category> categories = Lists.newArrayList(tools, animals);

public void stringConverter(String str)
{
    for (Category c : categories)
    {
        if (c.contains(str)) return c.getName();
    }

    return "not found";
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understood my question (and maybe it'se my fault, sorry for my worst english).

Comment: It should be something that it's automatically recognized. 
Group A (animals) = {cat, dog, horse)
Group B (tools) = {hammer, screwdriver}
If my method reads "cat", it should say: "your string is group A" and should return me "animals".

Comment: I'm confused. How does my suggestion not do this?

Comment: Is this limited to Strings?  This kind of sound like something enums would be good for.

Comment: I was thinking about enums but how can i use it? Limited to Strings.

Comment: Enums are compile time.  See comment to your OP. Yes, it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Map<String, String>` where the keys of the map are your 6 strings, and the value is either `"animal"` or `"tool"`. Use `map.get(str)` to get the type of the string.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this cat (npi;) -- here is one approach.  Annotations are another way to go.(e.g. Category is an annotation type with target type of field, etc.)  Obviously the comparison mechanism isn't done below but that is trivial.

```
public enum Category {
    animal, tool
}
public interface Categorized {
    Category getCategory();
}
public enum FarmAnimals implements Categorized {
    dog, cat, horse, rabbit;
    public Category getCategory() {
        return Category.animal;
    }
}
public enum GarageTools implements Categorized {
    screwdriver, drill, wrench;
    public Category getCategory() {
        return Category.tool;
    }
}
```

[edit: naturally, your enums can be of form dog ("Dog"), etc. if you need embedded spaces, etc.]